# 'Failed to get tabs for debugging' when trying to debug NodeJs with chrome debugger for Eclipse

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ubuntu, google-chrome-devtools

I have struggled this for couple of days without any success, please help me out.

What I am seeking is to find a better IDE for editing and debugging Node.js based JavaScript server code. I have successfully installed Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and followed link https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger installed Chrome debugger for Eclipse.However, when I tried to debug I encountered an error saying 'Failed to get tabs for debugging'[image: Debug error]

Here are the steps what I did:

1. Installed Node.js v0.10.0
2. Installed Eclipse IDE for JavaScript
3. Installed Chrome debugger for Eclipse by following https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger
4. Create a debug configuration under WebKit Protocol (refer to bottom picture)
5. Create a JavaScript project in Eclipse
6. Create a JavaScript source file in the project
7. Open a Ubuntu terminal and run the JavaScript source file: node debug test1.js
8. In Eclipse try debug with the custom debug configuration and the error happens.
9. PS: my Ubuntu is 12.04 64bit; NodeJs remote debug port is default 5858

Please help me on this, what did I missing from the steps?

[image: Eclipse debug configuration for Node.js]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #4 is incorrect. Should be "Standalone V8 VM".